# mysql query to get count of rows from 2 columns of same table on equal values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
given_answer   correct_answer
  1                 3
  4                 4
  3                 3
  1                 2
  2                 2
```

Both Columns in the same table, I need a count of matching values from both columns. (count is 3 in the above table)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more of what count you need of matching values ?

Comment: I need a row count of matching values in both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match the columns in where condition.

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM TABLE
WHERE given_answer = correct_answer
```